# Resize specific cells of array in c

Tags: c, string, resize, realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *readline()
{
   char s[256],*ds;
   printf("Give string: ");
   gets(s);
   ds = (char *) calloc(strlen(s)+1,sizeof(char));
   strcpy(ds,s);
   return ds;
}


main()
{
   char *s1,*s2;
   int a,b;
   s1=readline();
   printf("Start:");
   scanf("%d",&a);
   printf("End:");
   s2=(char*)realloc(s1,b-a);
   puts(s2);
   return 0;

}
```

I have this code and I want to resize specific cells of the s1 array which are determined from the variables `a` and `b`.
E.g. If I give the string `"Hello"` and the integers `a=2` and `b=4` then I want the program to print `"ell"`.

Comment: Why is `realloc` necessary to do that?

Comment: If there is another way then no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `gets` use `fgets` instead.

With `fgets` you would use `if( fgets( s,256, stdin)!= NULL ){ /*Got input in s*/ }`.
You have taken `\n` as input also. `s[strcspn(s,"\n")]=0` will overwrite `\n` with `\0`.

Casting return value of `calloc` is not needed since, `void*` will be implicitly converted to `char*`. `calloc` may return `NULL` - you didn't include check in there.

```
ds = calloc(strlen(s)+1,sizeof(char));
if( NULL == ds ){
    perror("calloc: error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

In `main()` value of `b` is indeterminate. You didn't take input in `b`.

```
if( scanf("%d",&b)!= 1){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error in input");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Then you `realloc`-ed. But not clear why. If you thought that shrinking the memory to `4-2` or `2` Bytes will help you get `"ell"` then you are wrong in many ways. It won't.

what you can do is - allocate memory for that in `s2`.

```
if(b<a){
  fprintf(stderr,"End must be greater than beginnning\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}
s2 = malloc(b-a+1);
if(!s2){
   perror("calloc: error");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
memcpy(s2,s1+a,b-a);
s2[b-a]=0;
puts(s2);
```

This will print the relevant `"ell"` just you wanted. There is one thing left for you - put the code snippets in the code.

Comment: Oh I see my thought was wrong from the start. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are open to other solutions:

> If there is another way then no problem.

I would point you to a simple solution, where you terminate the original string at `b` and skip required number of characters `a`. (Note: in C char array starts from index `0`);

This is the idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *splice(char *str, int s, int e)
{
    str[e]=0;
    return (str+s-1);
}

int main()
{
   char *after;

   int a=2;
   int b=4; 

   char original[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l' , 'l' , 'o', 0 };       

   after = splice(original,a,b);

   printf("My new string = %s", after);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
My new string = ell
```